# Delete keys in a certain age

Tags: redis, lua

I would like to go over million of keys and delete all the ones that remained 10 days or less to live.

I've got this

```
local cursor='0';
repeat
  local keysVar = {};
  local scanResult = redis.call('SCAN', cursor, 'MATCH', 'lucee-storage:session:*', 'COUNT', 100);
  local keys = scanResult[2];
  for i = 1, #keys do
    ttl = redis.call('TTL', keys[i]);
    if ttl < 864000 then
      keysVar[i] = keys[i];
    end;
  end;
  redis.call('UNLINK', unpack(keysVar));
  cursor = scanResult[1];
until cursor == '0';
```

The problem is that this runs forever which impacts prod. Ideally I would like something with redid-cli and pipeline.

Do you have ideas how to tune it?

Comment: You should not run scan in a loop with Lua script, which blocks Redis. Instead, run scan with redis-cli, and pass a limited number of the scanned keys to your script that do the TTL check and unlink work, i.e. run the loop on client side, instead of server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it from bash as I wanted:

```
redis-cli -h $HOST --scan --pattern 'keys:*' | 
xargs -L 1 echo "eval \"local ttl=redis.call('TTL', ARGV[1]); 
                        if ttl < 864000 then 
                          redis.call('UNLINK', ARGV[1]); 
                        end; 
                      \"
                      0 " > pipe

cat pipe | redis-cli -h $HOST --pipe
```

There's a pipe logic where I read in bulk of 5000 and send to reds